# Validate maven artifactid when using archetype:generate

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I am generating a project from an archetype and passing the properties, -DartifactId and other archetype properties.

I want to restrict the user to give a specific name for the project which he is generating. I wrote a plugin with phase as generate-sources. But it is not running. any other way to achieve this feature?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? What does your user call? What kind of restriction do you want to impose?

Comment: mvn archetype:generate -DartifactId=sample-ang-node -D blah blah. This is the command user will be executing to create angular project. I am required to restrict the user to use only small case letters for artifactId. This is required for the project to work with angular1.5 and on node ecosystem